# submit action is called twice on production server (RAILS)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a "remote form": `<form action="/payment_methods" class="new_credit_card_details" data-remote="true" id="new_credit_card_details" method="post">...</form>`

When I click the submit button, I can see in the chrome's developer tools panel that the /payment_methods request is made twice. (it happens in other browsers as well).
I tried to find a submit event handler in my JS and I couldn't, the only one seems to be the default, which is handled by jquery-ujs(I set remote = true).

Can you suggest me a way to check why it happens? I have to note that this bug doesn't occur on my development environment...

Comment: *"the only one seems to be the default, which is handled by jquery-ujs(I set remote = true)."* what is jquery-ujs? it's likely what's causing your problem.

Comment: jquery_ujs.js is a rails' plugin that add some capabilities, like having a data attribute "remote"=true on a form to make it an ajax form

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your remote form sends several requests
Try to add options `disable_with`, smth like this

```
<%= submit_tag "submit", :disable_with => "Processing" %>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'll check it later as I have no access to the production server now. Do you have ant idea way the form sends several requests?

Comment: for example double click

Comment: And I think that if reason not in double click then `disable_with` does not help you :-/

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not double click, so I'll look for other suggestions, thanks anyway